# How do I convert an array of [object, object]'s to html()?

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to figure this out :

```
$(".task:last").append(  

$("<div/>", {class: 'clear'}) +  
$("<div/>", {class: 'time', text: '3:30pm'}) +
$("<div/>", {class: 'clear'}) 

)
```

Unfortunately, this comes back as a bunch of [object, Object]. How do I append the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var first = $("<div/>", {"class": 'clear'}),
    second = $("<div/>", {"class": 'time', text: '3:30pm'}),
    third = $("<div/>", {"class": 'clear'}) ;
$(".task:last").append(first, second, third);
```

You can also try:

```
$(".task:last").append( 
    $("<div/>", {class: 'clear'}),
    $("<div/>", {class: 'time', text: '3:30pm'}),
    $("<div/>", {class: 'clear'})
);
```

Using Array:

```
var element = [
    $("<div/>", {class: 'clear'}),
    $("<div/>", {class: 'time', text: '3:30pm'}),
    $("<div/>", {class: 'clear'})
];

$.each(element, function() {
  this.appendTo('.task:last');
});
```

or

```
$.each(element, function() {
  $('.task:last').append(this);
});
```

**NOTE:**

Not `class: 'clear'`, is should `'class': 'clear'` or `className: 'clear'`. Because `class` is reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $(".task:last").append($("<div/>", { class: 'clear' }));
        $(".task:last").append($("<div/>", { class: 'time', text: '3:30pm' }));
        $(".task:last").append($("<div/>", { class: 'clear' }));
```

//Or

```
$(".task:last").append($("<div/>", { class: 'clear' }), $("<div/>", { class: 'time', text: '3:30pm' }), $("<div/>", { class: 'clear' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elms = [$("<div/>", {className: 'clear'}), 
            $("<div/>", {className: 'time', text: '3:30pm'}), 
            $("<div/>", {className: 'clear'}) 
           ];

$(".task:last").append(elms[0], elms[1], elms[2]);​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/66NwJ/)

or

```
var elms = [$("<div/>", {className: 'clear'}), 
            $("<div/>", {className: 'time', text: '3:30pm'}), 
            $("<div/>", {className: 'clear'}) 
           ];

$.each(elms, function() {
     $(this).appendTo(".task:last");
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = '3:30pm';
var $el = '<div class="clear" /><div class="time"> Time: '+t+'</div><div class="clear" />';
    $(".task:last").append( $el );
```

http://jsbin.com/izegut/edit#javascript,html,live